# issue with calling asp.net database function from WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have database function in main asp.net project and just created separate wcf project and trying to call database function in wcf. below code is one function in svc

```
public string ValidateUser(string username, string pwd)
{
    myApplication application = new myApplication();
    string resultString = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        resultString = application.Application.User.GetUserIdByUserName(username, pwd).ToString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    { resultString = "exception:" + e.Message; }

    return resultString;
}
```

What the database function does is check whether user name exist in table(MSSQL) and if it does it will return userId.

I thought it will be straight forward but every time I call this function I get `nullException error` and I guess it's because the database function when it complies, it looks up the connection string from `web.config` in main project but it stores **null** value.

I'm testing this locally with two VS open; one is main asp.net project with wcf project and another VS for console application to call this wcf.
Any suggestion or advise will be much appreciated.

Comment: You should separate the database code into a class library to be called by the WCF service and the ASP.NET application. The database code would have to change to be independent of ASP.NET. Nothing should be "calling" code in the ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify which `.config` file has the database connection string? The WCF service project or the ASP.NET project that calls it? The code running within the WCF service will get it's configuration from the WCF project's `.config` file, if the connection string isn't there, it won't get it from the caller.

Comment: i'm trying to get connection string from asp.net project. what wcf should do is to re-use existing functionalities from asp.net project. should I build functionalities from the scratch only for wcf? I really want to avoid duplication of code.

Comment: That's what I said in my comment, above. Separate the common code into a library, used by both.

Comment: that's already in library and when I call any function, this library looks up the connection string from web.config file in asp.net project.

Comment: Are you sure? The way it normally works is that code picks up configuration from _the current configuration_. In the case of a web application, that's the hierarchy of web.config files. In the case of a desktop application, that's "application.exe.config".

Comment: yes, I'm using library and whenever this library is called first thing it does is to grab connection string from asp.net project and fires required function. if I can give you structure of my solution, I have 3 projects including asp.net project, common project which has all the common functionalities stored and wcf project which calls functions from the common project and what common project.

Comment: @maxiSK: what do you mean by "grab connection string from asp.net project"? How is a library function called from a WCF host accessing the Web.config file of a separate website?

Comment: To clarify. We have 3 projects in our solution. 1 project is our web application. 1 project is our DAL and the new project is the WCF which we are setting up as our web service for external access. The DAL has no web.config, but the web app does. the DAL has been setup to read the web apps web.config file to set the connection string. Now that we are connecting the WCF to the DAL, we are getting a null exception on the connection string. Is that because its the web apps web.config being read?

Comment: Can you post a few lines of code from the DAL that is "reading the web app's web.config file"? Are you doing something with `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`? Because if so, when the WCF service calls that it will **not** access the web app's Web.config, it will access it's *own* config file.

Comment: below is code from our DAL file to get the connection string myConnection = CommonApplication.Configuration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["myConnectio‌​n"].ConnectionString;